# Subselection causes strange data changes (getting first N rows for every group)

Tags: mysql

Trying to get first N rows for every group.

Here is table:

```
CREATE TABLE `topics` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `is_hide` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_last_message` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_topic` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_start` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_section` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKl3nyk47e2emkctg3sjff38whr` (`id_section`),
  KEY `FKoc3papwmjontq89fcia02ag1h` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Sample data:

```
1 0 2019-11-01 topic1 2019-10-31 1 1
2 1 2019-11-01 topic2 2019-10-31 1 3
3 0 2019-11-01 topic3 2019-10-31 2 2
4 1 2019-11-01 topic4 2019-10-31 2 3
```

Group by `id_section` with `date_last_message` sorting.

So this query is work fine but adds one more column which numerates every row in a group:

```
select *,  (row_number() over (partition by id_section order by date_last_message desc)) i from topics
```

result is:

```
1   0   2019-11-01  topic1  2019-10-31  1   1   1
2   1   2019-11-01  topic2  2019-10-31  1   3   2
3   0   2019-11-01  topic3  2019-10-31  2   2   1
4   1   2019-11-01  topic4  2019-10-31  2   3   2
```

But, when I select over the result in such a way trying to get rid of last column:

```
select id, is_hide, date_last_message, name_topic, date_start, id_section, user_id 
from (
select *,  row_number() over (partition by id_section order by date_last_message desc) i from topics
) t 
where i <= 10
```

I get this:

```
1   1   2019-11-01  topic1  2019-10-31  1   1
2   1   2019-11-01  topic2  2019-10-31  1   3
3   1   2019-11-01  topic3  2019-10-31  2   2
4   1   2019-11-01  topic4  2019-10-31  2   3
```

So, as you can see the results in `is_hide` column become identical (to 1) and I dont know why. And this is the problem.

Comment: upd: if I ignore `name_topic` and execute following query
```select id, is_hide, date_last_message, date_start, id_section, user_id 
from (
select id, is_hide, date_last_message, date_start, id_section, user_id,  row_number() over (partition by id_section order by date_last_message desc) i from topics
) t 
where i <= 10```
data in `is_hide` does not change that way and stays original.

Comment: Is the row number really important? as the `ORDER BY` in `(row_number() over (partition by id_section order by date_last_message desc))` is used on non deterministic data with in a id_section group meaning you cant predict when record values are ties, which record will be first, second .....and so on meaning the results off `row_number()` are non deterministic (random)

Comment: .. most likely you want to add `id` column in the `ORDER BY` clause aswell.. `(row_number() over (partition by id_section order by date_last_message desc, id ASC/DESC))` to make results deterministic (fixed) and predictable always on every run..

Comment: Thanks for hint. Could be another aproach for mentioned problem different from mine?

Comment: *"So, as you can see the results in is_hide column become identical (to 1) and I dont know why. And this is the problem."*  that `BIT` datatype is your main problem use a `TINYINT` instead for boolean "flags".. as `BIT` datatype is a **bit** wierd in MySQL..  Consider [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k5KJM6mkuim9v5wfhzWPXy/2) vs [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k5KJM6mkuim9v5wfhzWPXy/6)

Comment: This is the answer! Thanks a lot!